# How to rename the fields of ejbql query in ireport?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, ireport, ejbql

I'm using iReport 3.7.3 with `ejbql` connection. My problem is when I want to get the fields from the query, the ireport sets the name of the fields with "COLUMN_1", "COLUMN_2" even if I use the sentence "as" the ireport gets me that name to the fields. Here's an example of my query:

`select doc.docId as DocumentID, doc.transactionDate as TransationDate from Document doc`

Answer (score 1):

1. right-click on the field
2. rename the field, e.g. `My_campo`
3. set description = COLUMN_1

Comment: (translated answer using Google Translate - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3620067/1) for original Spanish version)